# Переключение класса у соответствующих элементов

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, slider

При переключении thumbnail класс active отрабатывается корректно.
Но при переключении слайдов стрелками, на втором слайде фиксируется класс active.
Идея в том, чтобы при переключении стрелками, класс active переключался с сохранением соответствия элементов друг другу. (Например: Желтый - Желтый, Красный - Красный и т.д.)

Помогите разобраться

```js
var slideNow = 1;
    var slideCount = $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').children().length;
    var navBtnId = 0;
    var translateWidth = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#portfolio_slider .viewport').hover(
            function () {
                $('.slider_btns').css({'opacity' : '1', 'transition' : 'all ease 0.3s'});
            },
            function () {
                $('.slider_btns').css('opacity','0');
        });
        $('.slider_arrow').click(function() {
            $(".slider_wrap .slide,.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn").removeClass("active");
            $(".slider_nav .slider_nav_btn:eq(" + $(this).addClass("active").index() + ")").addClass('active')
        });
        $(".slider_nav .slider_nav_btn:eq(" + $(".slider_wrap .slide").index() + ")").addClass('active')
        
        $('.next_btn').click(function() {
            nextSlide();
        });
        $('.prev_btn').click(function() {
            prevSlide();
        });

        $('.slider_nav_btn').click(function() {
            $('.slider_nav_btn').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            navBtnId = $(this).index();

            if (navBtnId + 1 != slideNow) {
                translateWidth = -$('#portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * (navBtnId);
                $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
                    'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                });
                slideNow = navBtnId + 1;
            }
        });
    });


    function nextSlide() {
        if (slideNow == slideCount || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
            $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
            slideNow = 1;
        } else {
            translateWidth = -$('#portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * (slideNow);
            $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
                'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
            });
            slideNow++;
        }
    }

    function prevSlide() {
        if (slideNow == 1 || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
            translateWidth = -$('#portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * (slideCount - 1);
            $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
                'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
            });
            slideNow = slideCount;
        } else {
            translateWidth = -$('#portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * (slideNow - 2);
            $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
                'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
            });
            slideNow--;
        }
    }
```

```css
#portfolio_slider {
  width: 100%;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% * 5);
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide {
  width: calc(100%/5);
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .slide_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.red {
  background: red;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.blue {
  background: blue;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.green {
  background: green;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.purple {
  background: purple;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn,
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(25% - 25px);
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn:hover,
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn {
  left: 20px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn {
  right: 20px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider_nav {
 display: table;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn.active .thumbnail_slide {
  border: 3px solid #333;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.red {
  background: red;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.green {
  background: green;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.purple {
  background: purple;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="portfolio_slider">
        <div class="viewport">
            <div class="slider_wrap">
                <div class="slide active"><div class="main_slide red"></div></div>
                <div class="slide"><div class="main_slide blue"></div></div>
                <div class="slide"><div class="main_slide green"></div></div>
                <div class="slide"><div class="main_slide purple"></div></div>
                <div class="slide"><div class="main_slide yellow"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider_btns">
                <div class="prev_btn slider_arrow"> PREV </div>
                <div class="next_btn slider_arrow"> NEXT </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="slider_nav">
    <div class="slider_nav_btn active"><div class="thumbnail_slide red"></div></div>
    <div class="slider_nav_btn"><div class="thumbnail_slide blue"></div></div>
    <div class="slider_nav_btn"><div class="thumbnail_slide green"></div></div>
    <div class="slider_nav_btn"><div class="thumbnail_slide purple"></div></div>
    <div class="slider_nav_btn"><div class="thumbnail_slide yellow"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то перемудрили) Можно было еще сократить код, но не трогал остальные куски, чтобы лишний раз не запутать. Комментарии только там, где были изменения:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // всё обернул в ready, потому что сильно захотелось.
  var slideNow = 0; // в JS счет начинается с нуля.
  var slideCount = $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').children().length;
  var navBtnId = 0;
  var translateWidth = 0;

  $('#portfolio_slider .viewport').hover(
    function () {
      $('.slider_btns').css({'opacity' : '1', 'transition' : 'all ease 0.3s'});
    },
    function () {
      $('.slider_btns').css('opacity','0');
    });
  $('.slider_arrow').click(function() {
    $(".slider_wrap .slide,.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn").removeClass("active");
    $(".slider_nav .slider_nav_btn:eq(" + $(this).addClass("active").index() + ")").addClass('active')
  });
  $(".slider_nav .slider_nav_btn:eq(" + $(".slider_wrap .slide").index() + ")").addClass('active')

  $('.next_btn').click(function() {
    nextSlide();
  });
  $('.prev_btn').click(function() {
    prevSlide();
  });

  $('.slider_nav_btn').click(function() {
    $('.slider_nav_btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    navBtnId = $(this).index();

    if (navBtnId + 1 != slideNow) {
      translateWidth = -$('#portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * (navBtnId);
      $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      });
      slideNow = navBtnId + 1;
    }
  });

function nextSlide() {
  /* slideNow = ... перед тем как дать ему значение - запускаем проверку. 
  slideNow равен slideCount - 1 ? если да, то ему дальше некуда расти, возвращается на 0
  а если нет, увеличится на единицу.*/
  slideNow = (slideNow == slideCount - 1) ? 0 : ( slideNow + 1 );
  translateWidth = -$('#portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * ( slideNow );
  $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
  });
  
  /* Убираем класс со всех кнопок, добавляем его на текущую, по индексу */
  $('.slider_nav_btn').removeClass('active');
  $('.slider_nav_btn').eq(slideNow).addClass('active');
}

/* Та же история, только в другую сторону */
function prevSlide() {  
  slideNow = (slideNow == 0) ? (slideCount - 1) : slideNow - 1;
  translateWidth = -$('#portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * ( slideNow );
  $('#portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
  });
  $('.slider_nav_btn').removeClass('active');
  $('.slider_nav_btn').eq(slideNow).addClass('active');
}

});
```

```css
#portfolio_slider {
  width: 100%;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% * 5);
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide {
  width: calc(100%/5);
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .slide_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.red {
  background: red;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.blue {
  background: blue;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.green {
  background: green;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.purple {
  background: purple;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .main_slide.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn,
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(25% - 25px);
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn:hover,
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn {
  left: 20px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn {
  right: 20px;
}
#portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider_nav {
 display: table;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn.active .thumbnail_slide {
  border: 3px solid #333;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.red {
  background: red;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.green {
  background: green;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.purple {
  background: purple;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn .thumbnail_slide.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="portfolio_slider">
        <div class="viewport">
            <div class="slider_wrap">
                <div class="slide active"><div class="main_slide red"></div></div>
                <div class="slide"><div class="main_slide blue"></div></div>
                <div class="slide"><div class="main_slide green"></div></div>
                <div class="slide"><div class="main_slide purple"></div></div>
                <div class="slide"><div class="main_slide yellow"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider_btns">
                <div class="prev_btn slider_arrow"> PREV </div>
                <div class="next_btn slider_arrow"> NEXT </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="slider_nav">
    <div class="slider_nav_btn active"><div class="thumbnail_slide red"></div></div>
    <div class="slider_nav_btn"><div class="thumbnail_slide blue"></div></div>
    <div class="slider_nav_btn"><div class="thumbnail_slide green"></div></div>
    <div class="slider_nav_btn"><div class="thumbnail_slide purple"></div></div>
    <div class="slider_nav_btn"><div class="thumbnail_slide yellow"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас от всей души. Ваш код конечно логичнее.
А где еще перемудрил?
И еще такой вопрос: логичнее ли будет использовать для элементов список li нежели div? Или это на вкус и цвет?